# my bot suddenly stopped responding to my messages after the 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i was working normally on my own discord bot and i created my first slash commands and when i ran the cmd it worked and everything was perfectly fine then i closed the cmd and discord and everything

The other day i opened discord and i ran the cmd again to find my bot not responding to any of my commands even the /finish command and it always gave the error "The application did not respond" ive tried editing some of the vsc scripts about the bot acually reading the commands, checked the permissions on discord, removed the bot from the server and added it again,even searching for the problem i couldnt really find anyone that had the same issue ,i did almost everything but i have no clue to what to do now.
and i dont know which script should i exactly share because i dont know what type of problem im really running into

my main code

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, GatewayIntentBits } = 
require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] 
});

client.commands = new Collection();
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = 
fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => 
file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} 
is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}


const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => 
file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => 
event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => 
event.execute(...args));
        }
}

client.login(token);
```

and this is to execute the commands i dont know if its going to help

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you                 created earlier
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    // Grab all the command files from the commands directory you     created earlier
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file     => file.endsWith('.js'));
    // Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each     command's data for deployment
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is     missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST().setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length}     application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in     the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

            console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} 
    application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you able to provide your code? It's needed so we can find the issue.